# MS Office SQL create table error

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013, create-table

This is not good.. I just started to use sql because of my school course.. i had choice of only ms access .. in my first attemp only i am getting error :

**Syntax eror in create table statement**

My code was :

```
CREATE TABLE EMP (EMP_CODE INT PRIMARY KEY, SALARY INT, DESIG CHAR[20]);
```

now how to make it work perfectly ??

Comment: Use parentheses for the 20 not square braces.

Comment: can you mention, the error you are encountering?

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code :

```
CREATE TABLE EMP
   ( 
      EMP_CODE number PRIMARY KEY, 
      SALARY number, 
      [Desig] char(20)
   );
```

> Use the following data Type :
>
> ```
> 1. Number for Digit.
> 2. Char for character.
> 3. varchar for character and Digit.
> 4. Date for Date.
> ```

Comment: Thanks  for Proper Formatting #Huseyin BurakKaradag

Answer (score 0):

You were almost correct, change the square brackets `[]` to round brackets`()` after `char` .Your new query should now be

```
CREATE TABLE EMP (EMP_CODE INT PRIMARY KEY, SALARY INT, DESIG CHAR (20));
```

Comment: this worked... that was a really small mistake... i am habit of [ ] because of c++ :p